# How do I align a div containing text and a div containing an image on the same line in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I have a parent div containing two children divs. One div child contains text, and one div child contains an image. I'm trying to put them on the same line. I've tried a lot of things but they just can't seem to stay on the same line. If I use white-space: nowrap for the parent div, the text in the text div goes outside the div borders.

```css
CSS:
#block_container
    {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
    }
    #introduction
    {
     width: 60%;
     height: 400px;
     float: left;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    #image
    {
     width: 40%;
     height: 400px;
     float:right;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
HTML:
    <div id="block_container">
        <div id = "introduction">
      <h1 id="title">something</h1>
      <p id="paragraph">something</p>
     </div>
     <div id = "image">
      <img src="image.jpg" width="536px" height="400px" align = "right"/>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline-block from both the image and div, and make their display style inline.

```css
CSS:
#block_container
    {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
    }
    #introduction
    {
     width :59%
     height: 400px;
     float: left;
     border:red solid 
    }
    #image
    {
     width: 39%;
     height: 400px;
     float:right;
     
    }
    #introduction #image
    {
    display:inline
    }
```

```html
HTML:
    <div id="block_container">
       <div id = "introduction">
        <h1 id="title">something</h1>
        <p id="paragraph">something</p>
       </div>
       <div id = "image">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
       </div>
      </div>
```

div without width

```css
CSS:
#block_container
    {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
    }
    #introduction
    {
     
     height: 400px;
     float: left;
     border:red solid 
    }
    #image
    {
     width: 39%;
     height: 400px;
     
     
    }
    #introduction #image
    {
    display:inline
    }
```

```html
HTML:
    <div id="block_container">
       <div id = "introduction">
        <h1 id="title">something</h1>
        <p id="paragraph">something</p>
       </div>
       <div id = "image">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That didn't really help unfortunately, still my text is on one line in the left, then there is the gap where the image is supposed to fit, then on the following line in the right there's the image.

Comment: The image can't fit there as the div has occupied that space with the width 0% which you provided. I gave it a border color to provide distinction. They are stuck together, its just that the div has a width which is resulting in white space. You can remove the with and then the white space will be gone